# Breaking long lines with comparison operators in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, syntax

in my bash code sometimes I use long parameters in Comparison Operators to test the "OR"

as the following:

```
if [[ $production_check_linux_disks_quantity == false  ]] || [[ $production_linux_mount_point_reference_to_ambari_definition == false ]] || [[ $production_check_linux_mount_point_quantity == false ]] || [[ $production_show_linux_disks_simulation == false ]]
then
```

problem is that syntax is too long and ugly

some idea how to create it shorter and elegant?

Comment: I would recommend to not use such long variable names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the line on the `||`. In fact, you can break the line at any [control operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222). So, at any of `||`, `!`, `&&`, `&`, `;`, `;;`, `|`, `|&`, `(`, or `)`.

This is correct syntax for your example, for instance, there's no need for `\`:

```
if [[ $production_check_linux_disks_quantity == false  ]] || 
   [[ $production_linux_mount_point_reference_to_ambari_definition == false ]] || 
   [[ $production_check_linux_mount_point_quantity == false ]] || 
   [[ $production_show_linux_disks_simulation == false ]]; then
    echo yes
fi
```

You do need `\` to connect multiple lines if they don't end with a control operator, but not when they do.

Also, note that `if [[ $var == false ]]` is checking whether the value of the variable `$var` is the string `false`, and is better written as `if [[ $var = 'false' ]]`. Your code suggests that you might be expecting it to evaluate to true if `$var` is -1 or 0 or unset or something.

Comment: dose -  &&  work the same as ||  ??

Comment: @yael yes, all of the operators I list in the second sentence can end lines.